# Row text from a dynamic table

Tags: extjs, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am pretty new to Selenium Webdriver, so pardon me for all d 'noob' terminology used.

I have a dynamic table on the page, with 4 columns in the table. Out of this, only the first column name can be edited. The table looks like this :

[image: (sorry, stack overflow wont let me post images)]

Now using Webdriver, I need to locate 'group102' and verify the Level and the number of Cards (basically the text of the rest of the two columns) corresponding to 'group102'. The key point to note here is that this group is dynamic in nature. Right now, its sitting in row 3 but tomorrow, it may be on row 1 or row 10.

I am using Visual Studio (C#) and Selenium webdriver. 
Please let me know how can I progress

EDIT :
HTML CODE:

```html
<div id="formbland-1013" class="x-panel x-panel-default x-form-bland x-form-base" style="height: 9588px;">
 <div id="formbland-1013-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-panel-body-default" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 680px; height: 9588px;">
  <span id="formbland-1013-outerCt" style="display: table; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
   <div id="formbland-1013-innerCt" style="display:table-cell;height:100%;vertical-align:top;">
    <div id="ext-comp-1026" class="x-panel x-panel-default x-form-bland x-form-base" style="width: 680px; height: 47px;">
     <div id="ext-comp-1036" class="x-panel x-panel-default x-form-bland x-form-base" style="width: 680px; height: 9541px;">
      <div id="ext-comp-1036-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-panel-body-default" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 680px; height: 9541px;">
       <span id="ext-comp-1036-outerCt" style="display: table; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
        <div id="ext-comp-1036-innerCt" style="display:table-cell;height:100%;vertical-align:top;">
```

CODE WHICH I AM TRYING :

```cs
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> select = WebDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//td[contains(text(),'group102')]"));
if ("group102e".Equals(select.ToString()))
{
    throw new SystemException("Group matches according to the Access");
}
else
{
    throw new SystemException("Group does not matches according to the Access");
}
```

Comment: DOM ?? If you are asking about the code, I am still trying to get to build it. I am not sure on how to progress on it.

Comment: I used a locator to find one of the area. The code which I used :  var location =  WebDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("tbody input[value='Practice Wide Group 2']")).Location.ToString();

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide exact code as I don't know the HTML for the table. But here are the code in theory.

You get the `IWebElement` input first by text first, then go to ancestor td's siblings (i.e. the next two column cells in this row), then get the element's text.

```c#
IWebElement inputGroup = WebDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("tbody input[value='group101']"));
IWebElement level = inputGroup.FindElement(By.XPath("(.//ancestor::td/following-sibling::td)[1]"));
string levelA = level.Text;
```

My questions about your code:

1. `"group102e".Equals(select.ToString())` doesn't make sense, since your `select` is `ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>`, which is a list of IWebElements, `ToString` won't get you anything useful?
2. `var location = WebDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("tbody input[value='Practice Wide Group 2']")).Location.ToString();`, what do you want here? The location of the element (which is in the type of `System.Drawing.Point`)?

Comment: Like I said - I am pretty new to whole Selenium Webdriver thing ( IDE was so much simpler !! )... I am just learning new stuff...thanks to the intellisense from the visual studio...

Comment: Guys, I am still stuck at the same place. I am not sure how this works but the 'table' which I was talking about is more of a form. The form ( which is like a table has 3 columns - first one is a text box, the second one is a label and the third one is a label too..

Comment: <table id="ext-gen6002" class="x-table-layout" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="" class="x-table-layout-cell " rowspan="1" colspan="1">
<td id="" class="x-table-layout-cell " rowspan="1" colspan="1">
<td id="" class="x-table-layout-cell " rowspan="1" colspan="1">
<td id="" class="x-table-layout-cell " rowspan="1" colspan="1">
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>

Comment: @user2434600: I still can't see `tbody input[value='Practice Wide Group 2']` in your HTML. If you want the exact answer, please edit your question with complete HTML for the table. Otherwise, you need to play and debug the answer above yourself.

Comment: @user2434600: Also, what did not work exactly? Exceptions or anything? If you tried my answer, you would spot one mistake I made, `IWebElement level = inputGroup.FindElement` not `IWebElement level = WebDriver.FindElement`

Comment: @user2434600: Do you have any feedback on this? Did it work for you?